# CSS Crossfade image

Tags: html, css, fading

I have this code that works great. When I pass the mouse over the image it crossfades to another image.

What I want is: when I pass over the mouse the image crossfade and rest like this, I mean, make only 1 transition.

**1)image 1
2)onmouseover image 2
3)onmouse out image 2**

**here my code:**

```
    <div id="crossfade">
<img class="bottom" src="images/site3/pasarela1.png" />
<img class="top" src="images/site3/pasarela2.png" />
</div>
```

**here my css code:**

```
#crossfade {
position:relative;
height:250px;
width:400px;
}
#crossfade img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img.top:hover {
opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: For these kind of questions, it's best to post a jsFiddle, such as [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/5wwW8/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I get is that you want the :hover state to "stick". Though it's not a pure CSS solution, a solid way to handle this is if you are using jquery's .addClass.

```
$('.yourimage').mouseover(function() { //hover over your image to trigger the event
     $(this).addClass('yourAnimationClass'); //add the animation class to the image you hovered over
});
```

Comment: Make sure you have the jquery library included in your site.... 
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
.. and place the above code inside script tags.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.yourimage').mouseover(function() { //hover over your image to trigger the event
     $(this).addClass('yourAnimationClass'); //add the animation class to the image you hovered over
   });
});
</script>

Comment: Thank very much Mike! I go to try it;)

Comment: is not possible make it, chanching a bit the css code? It would a easy solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Nah, there's only :hover which will trigger the ON and OFF states. You'll need some sort of javascript to keep the class on there. Are you unable to get this to work?

Comment: yeah, i have tryied but with not results. I have made some error.